# Console.log page content before exit

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Sometimes my puppeteer program hangs forever because of an unhandled promise, so I figured I start the program with a setTimeout that closes it.

```
var page;
var content;

const maxExecTime = 1000*60*5; // 5 min
setTimeout(function(){
    content = page.content();
    console.log('TIMEOUT');
    console.log(content);
    process.exit()
}, maxExecTime);

(async () => {      
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('URL');

    ...

    await browser.close();
})();
```

My goal would be to console.log the last content of the page before the program closes, but the setTimeout is outside the async function so I can't use await, and I got:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

How can I achive my goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to await for the timeout function, each function requires it's own async keyword.

```
var page;
var content;

const maxExecTime = 1000*60*5; // 5 min
setTimeout(await function(){
    content = await page.content();
    console.log('TIMEOUT');
    console.log(content);
    process.exit()
}, maxExecTime);

(async () => {      
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('URL');

    ...

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: It works if I change two things :) Instead `setTimeout(await function()` should be `setTimeout(async function()` and `content = page.content()` should be `content = await page.content()`. Thanks.

Comment: I would also recommend separating those into named functions for clarity.